# How to make auto generate number for text box in C#

Tags: c#

I want to Insert auto generate number show in textbox when form is loaded **(like 000000001)** in database that not define primary key and  if table number found 0 then it increment every time when form  open by user to entry data. Please help me how to do it. I am using **C#.** 
Thanks

its working , but I need to from table filed.

```
public void RetriveWorkRequestNo ()
    {
        try
        {
            string query = "SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('WorkRequests')";
            if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                conn.Open();

            }
            SqlCommand cmdwr = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
            SqlDataReader reader = cmdwr.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                int value = int.Parse(reader[0].ToString()) + 1;
                textWorkRequestNo.Text = value.ToString("0000000000");
                textWorkRequestNo.ReadOnly = true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: `1` is a number, the leading zeds can only be expressed as string. ..and it isnt really AutoIncrement if you have code doing it.  Just insert a Date or something when the app starts

Comment: This design is just begging for concurrency problems.  I would recommend against it.

Comment: How to do it when open a form in textbox will show like Serial Number? @Plutonix

Comment: Why do you think you need to show this autoincrement ID to te user? If that's the DB table PK, then what value does it have for the user?

Comment: We have no idea *what* you are trying to do, just how you think it should be done.  What are you trying to count? Times the form is opened?  Time the app has run? Is there more than one user? Is it per-user? You could use `string.format` on the actual number once you figure out what it is

Comment: Its not a primary key ,  needs to show it to the user because its a work Number that keep user in hardcopy @LucMorin

Comment: Needs to show it to the user because its a work Number that keep user in hard-copy , I want to count it using table filled that's not primary key @Plutonix

Comment: @Tanvir, like Paul said, you need to think this through. First, do you want to allow multiple concurrent users? Even if not, must that number be unique in the table?

Comment: Yes, number should be unique. Please give me example dear @LucMorin Thanks again

Comment: @Tanvir, I still don't have enough information to give you a final answer. For now I'm voting to close this question as being too broad. Please edit your question and provide all relevant details. Don't use comments to provide those details, but rather edit your original question.

Comment: Catching an exception only to rethrow it doesn't really add anything useful.

Comment: Dear @LucMorin, As per guideline your I already edit my post and sorry for poor English.

Comment: Thanks dear @BrianRasmussen

Comment: I think I get what you are trying to do; setting aside best practices, the one thing that is still confusing is whether or not this unique number is consumed even if the user does not complete the form. IE: user A starts form and has form ID 01, user B starts form (before user A finishes) and has form ID 02, if user A does not finish the form, what happens to their form ID?

Comment: That's a good point out. if user don't complete the form number taken which user already save the data. Have you any idea to solve this problem? @LawrenceJohnson

Comment: The answer I proposed would allow it so that discarded IDs (abandoned forms) would just never be saved to your table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally  I have done it using  Sequence in MS SQL Server 2012

```
private int RetriveWorkRequestID()
    {

        try
        {
            string query = "SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR sqWorkRequests";
            if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                conn.Open();

            }
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
            {
                using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {

                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        int value = int.Parse(reader[0].ToString());
                        string date = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyMM");
                        WorkRequestID = Convert.ToInt32(date.ToString() + value.ToString("000"));
                    }
                }

            }

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        finally
        {

            if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                conn.Close();
            }

        }
        return WorkRequestsID;
    }
```